# Pandas Data frame counting how many times certain value appears in column if and only if other columns meet certain condition

Tags: python, pandas

I need help with pandas data frame. Trying to count all rows with a '1' value under particular column A if and only if other columns B,C,D,E,F,G are NOT blank. Any ideas?

Comment: this is easier if you break it down into steps: 1) filter dataframe where B, C, D, E, F, G are not blank 2) use [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) to get the counts of column A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a pandas data frame `df` with columns ABCDEFG

```
df_modified=df.dropna(subset = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']) #filter out rows that have NA in the listed columns
df_modified['A'].value_counts() #count the rows
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, khuynh, and thank you for your help too, Prachiti!  The problem I'm having is there are OTHER columns involved as well as the B,C,D,E,F,G columns (I do need those to NOT be blank); however, I have other columns following the G column, such as H, I, J, K and L.  Dropna() is dropping rows where H, I, J, K, or L are blank and I need Dropna to only work on columns B,C,D,E,F,G only.  Any ideas on how to get dropna to work specifically in terms of certain columns?  Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: @New_to_Python modified my answer